# Unable to see and resolve conflicts

Tags: git, terminal

Couple of things going on, i got a branch which says i got conflicts, [image: Shows there is a conflict], but i tried to see diff between two branches by `git diff branch1..branch2`, yet nothing. I don't see any conflict markers in my any files and i am clueless of what to do. I tried making a new branch, but that didn't help too. It seem like the folders in that branch don't get copied. I check .gitignore but nothing. How can i

1. Check what is being conflicted
2. Fix the conflict
3. merge it or at least be able to get a list of everything from files/folder from repo on that branch.

Sorry but i am new at this so, step by step would be helpful.I am using beanstalkapp
EDIT: I see changes such as

```
 diff --git a/Gruntfile.js b/Gruntfile.js
index 800049e..baf67c3 100644
--- a/Gruntfile.js
+++ b/Gruntfile.js
and diff --git a/skin/frontend/enterprise/cool/css/footer.css b/skin/frontend/enterprise/cool/css/footer.css
index d48ade5..b23c50c 100644
--- a/skin/frontend/enterprise/cool/css/footer.css
+++ b/skin/frontend/enterprise/cool/css/footer.css
```

but when i see those files, there are no conflict markers.

Answer (score 0):

Conflicts occur *during a merge*, not *on a branch*.  It's not immediately obvious to me what your GUI is showing you.  (It seems to have something to do with this "beanstalkapp".  Unfortunately there's no StackOverflow tag for beanstalkapp.)

To see what is conflicted once you have started a merge, use `git status`, which will include stuff like this:

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   plates.tex
```

The file in question (here `plates.tex`) will contain the conflict markers.  You simply edit the file until it is correct (usually by choosing one side or the other of the merge).

Sometimes you will find that both side of the merge are wrong and will have to come up up with a replacement.  Be very careful if you do this; it may be better to stop this merge and re-work the other branch, adding new commits that make it merge better.  A merge that introduces a change that was not made on either side is also known as an *evil merge*, since it can be very hard to find out where that cryptic change came from, later.

Comment: i don't see any conflict markers in my files, whereas it says i have problem with my gruntfile, when open, no conflict markers there `diff --git a/Gruntfile.js b/Gruntfile.js
index 800049e..baf67c3 100644
--- a/Gruntfile.js
+++ b/Gruntfile.js`

Comment: What is the output of `git status`?  Do you have any unusual settings (if you're new to git I suppose you might not know :-) ), e.g., a `.gitattributes` file or some interesting settings for Windows-vs-Linux end-of-line handling?